# Может ли погоня развернуться?

Tags: лексика, лексическая-сочетаемость

Может ли погоня развернуться? Насколько эти слова лексически сочетаемы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вполне. У глагола развернуться есть значение "осуществиться в полной мере,в широких размерах".Работа развернулась. События развернулись.Соревнования развернулись. И погоня может быть широкомасштабной и развернуться.

Может быть другой контекст: погоня растянулась на большое расстояние и далеко видна - тоже можно сказать "развернулась". Вот живописная картина может развернуться, и погоня может развернуться как картина перед глазами.

А может и в прямом смысле развернуться - повернуться в обратную сторону.

Нужен контекст, что именно Вас насторожило.